# Admin fails authentication in mongodb when running spring application

Tags: java, mongodb, docker

I created a spring application with the following configuration for connecting to MongoDB in application.yml:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: TestApp
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      username: username
      password: password
      authentication-database: admin
```

MongoDB itself runs in docker, launched using the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - db_data:/data
mongo-express:
  image: mongo-express
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
  environment:
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: username
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://username:password@mongo:27017/
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

I created an entity with fields on which I annotate indexes. When I run the application I get an error

> Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'Command createIndexes requires authentication' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Command createIndexes requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized"}

The login and password in application.yml match to docker-compose, I was able to log in manually in the terminal. Why can't spring authenticate to Mongo at startup?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470